# reload pickerview depending on data in textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerviewcontroller

I'm using Swift 3.
Here is the code:

```
public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if (selectedstatename == nil) {
        return dataList.count
    } else {
       return dataList1.count
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if (selectedstatename == nil) {
        return dataList[row].title
    } else {
        return dataList1[row].dist
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if (selectedstatename == nil) {
        cityField.text = dataList[row].title
        selectedstatename = cityField.text
        self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        cityField.resignFirstResponder()
    } else {
        self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        cat.text = dataList1[row].dist
        cat.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: what issue ur facing

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: you need to work with `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` UITextFieldDelegate method or with `textFieldDidEndEditing`